# I'm generating a random number generator in visual C++, and reset button isn't working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

i m trying to generate a random number generator in visual C++, and everything seems to working except the reset button

## pragma endregion

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             // Reset button
             System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
                 ; {
    
             // clear label fields
             this->label1->Text = "0";
             this->label2->Text = "0";
             this->label3->Text = "0";
             this->label4->Text = "0";
             this->label5->Text = "0";
             this->label6->Text = "0";
             this->label7->Text = "0";

             // set button state
             this->button1->Enabled = false;
             this->button2->Enabled = true;
}
```

this is the code i placed into the reset button.

Comment: I think you have to put `button1_Click` outside of the scope of the function `MyForm_Load`

Comment: This is actually C++/CLI. It is not C++!

Comment: @Rakete1111 okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put `button1_click` code outside of the `MyForm_Load` function and then it will work for sure!